# Javascript: return multiple values from different functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return multiple values from different functions.
The starting point is a bidimensional array. An example of the code is:

```
var items = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,2]];
var a;
var b;

function first() {
a = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
return a;
}

function second() {
b = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
return b;
}

function third (){
  first();
  second();
}

third();
```

If I write the code outside the functions, everything works fine. When I use functions and replace return with console.log, it works. If I use functions and return (as in the code reported above), it gives me undefined. I didn't find solutions. Why the code isn't working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What gives you undefined ? What do you want `third()` to do ?

Comment: `a` and `b` are both defined after you execute `third()`.

Comment: Your functions are returning a value as is correct but you are not doing anything with the values. What do you want to do with the values ?

Comment: If you want `third` to return something, then you need write a `return` statement in `third`.

Comment: `var third = _ => [first(),second()];` could be a start.

Answer (score 2):

If you are declaring variable a and b outside function(like in your code) than there is no need to return the values. a and b will get defined.
But if you are not declaring it outside, then store the return values in array variable.

```
var items = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,2]];

function first() {
a = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
return a;
}

function second() {
b = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
return b;
}

function third (){
var a = first();
var b = second();
var arr  = [];
arr.push(a);
arr.push(b);
return arr 
}

var t = third();
console.log(t[0], t[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want third to return values, add a return in it.

```
function third (){
  var a = [];
  a.push(first())
  a.push(second())
  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like

```
function third (){
  return {a: first(), b: second()};
}
```

then

```
var t = third()
console.log(t.a, t.b)
```

or if you're running on ES6

```
var {a,b} = third()
console.log(a, b)
```

see **Destructuring assignment** for further details